# MLflow run example gives me CommandNotFoundError

Tags: python, project, conda, virtual-environment, mlflow

I was trying to run the mlflow run exercise in the anaconda prompt, and it keeps giving me the error.
I'm using mlflow version 1.40, and the code above works fine if I execute it with --no-conda

`mlflow run https://github.com/mlflow/mlflow-example -P alpha=0.5` - doesn't work

`mlflow run https://github.com/mlflow/mlflow-example -P alpha=0.5 --no-conda` - works

It gives me the error when activating the conda environment. The specific conda environment works fine if I manually activate it. It just doesn't work within the mlflow command.

[image: capture of prompt]

[image]

Comment: How is your .bashrc configured? Have you run `conda init bash`, as suggested?

Comment: @merv I have uploaded the result after `conda init bash`. I tried as suggested, but it didn't work. Manually activating the environments works though

Comment: Oh, sorry. I just noticed your in Windows. What shell are you actually running? `bash` might have been the wrong suggestion.